# Xamarin Device.OpenUri

Tags: pdf, xamarin

I am using Device.OpenUri to open a pdf document.  I tried using WebView, but it would not load the pdf.  My code works fine on the Windows Phone emulators.  The webpage opens and downloads the pdf while the app runs in the background.  I recently purchased a cheap Windows Phone to test on and when I debug my code on the actual device it works as well.  The problem I am having is when I install the app on the device and run it the webpage opens and displays the pdf, but the app closes for some reason.

I have never seen this before.  Is there a reason the code will run on a Windows Phone emulator, on a Windows Phone (debug), but not on the Windows Phone installed?